# Access an array index from a function call

Tags: php, arrays, function, indexing, echo

I have an array like

```
$remarks = array('Poor','Fair','Good');
```

I want to access the array index by function call in it.

```
echo $remarks[myindex($id)];
```

where myindex() is a function which returns some number value from database.

How can I access the array index of my array at run time

Comment: You mean `myindex($remarks[$id]);` instead ?

Comment: `array_keys()` perhaps?

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran
no myindex is a function which returns a value between 0-2 then I want to display array value of that index

Comment: A lot of question marks. You're perhaps asking yourself what the numbers for the keys are? PHP uses zero-based indexes, so it is `0`, `1` and `2` for `$remarks` after `$remarks = array('Poor','Fair','Good');`. http://php.net/array

Answer (score 2):

As per you say..

> myindex is a function which returns a value between 0-2 then I want to
>   display array value of that index

```
<?php
$remarks = array('Poor','Fair','Good');

function myIndex()
{
    return rand(0,2);
}

echo $remarks[myIndex()]; //"prints" either Poor , Fair or Good randomly..
```

The `myIndex()` function returns a random value between 0,1 or 2 , so that is passed as the index value to your array and it prints the values either `Poor , Fair or Good`.

Answer (score 1):

it may be

```
function myindex($id){
   return $id % 3;
}
```